# nohup works only for a few minutes after logout

Tags: ssh, php, nohup

I connect to a remote server via SSH. And I want to run a php program in the background on the server after I log out. I have tried using "nohup", but the program only works for a few minutes and then stop. The program has a while (true) loop which is supposed to run forever.
My command is like:

```
nohup php -f index.php &
```

I have also tried using " disown -h %1" as is suggested in the following link, but it has the same problem
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-programme-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh][1]

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Does the program is running forever without `nohup`, while the terminal window is open? Without the content of the script no one can say where the problem is. Probably there is a lack of resources and your program is killed due to insufficient RAM, etc.

Comment: @pa4080 Yes, it runs forever if the terminal is open (whether nohup is used or not). In fact my program does not take much RAM, it simply prints the timestamp every 10 senconds. If I close the terminal, it can still run but only for a few minutes. It's just for a test.